# Deserialising Generic object results in null value for T in azure functions

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, azure-durable-functions

I have a class from a library, so I have no control on the class. Here is is:

```
public class EventLog<T> : IEventLog
    {
        public EventLog(T eventObject, FilterLog log)
        {
            Event = eventObject;
            Log = log;
        }

        public T Event { get; }
        public FilterLog Log { get; }
    }
```

I am getting a list of these. (a List<EventLog>)
When I return this list from my activity function to the orchestrator, the `T Event` is null.

Having been playing about / googling the last few hours, I am no closer. I have a simplified test, where I have an orchestrator call an activity function and pass in a single `EventLog<DepositEvent>` as the input. Calling `context.GetInput<EventLog<DepositEvent>>()` on the activity function also results in the `T Event` being null.

In startup I have set the JsonSerializerSettings such that `TypeNameHandling` is `TypeNameHandling.All`. I have decorated the DepositEvent with `[JsonObject]` and `[JsonProperty]` on the parameters.

Whilst debugging, inspecting the non public members of context from the activity function I can see the serialised input. The serialised input has the typename as I would expect from the settings, and it has all the information. It is only when it is deserialised that it just makes the `T Event` null...

A sample of the beginning of the serialised JSON:

```
{
  "$type": "System.Object[], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
  "$values": [
    {
      "$type": "Nethereum.Contracts.EventLog`1[[xxx.xxx.Events.DepositEvent, xxx.xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Nethereum.Contracts, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8768a594786aba4e",
      "Event": {
        "$type": "xxx.xxx.Events.DepositEvent, xxx.xxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "From": "0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
        "TokenId": 18082448916451024430800726619787705340592747687914198471720709142354080950600,
        "DomainLabel": "pingutest7"
      },
      "Log": {
        "$type": "Nethereum.RPC.Eth.DTOs.FilterLog, Nethereum.RPC, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8768a594786aba4e",
        "removed": false,
........
```

So, I have absolutely everything required there to deserialise without issue I would think? I really cannot work out why the deserialisation doesn't work...

The DepositEvent class is:

```
[Event("Deposit")]
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class DepositEvent : IEventDTO
{
    [Parameter("address", "_from", 1, true)]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("From")]
    public string From { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter("uint256", "_id", 2, true)]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("TokenId")]
    public BigInteger TokenId { get; set; }

    [Parameter("string", "_domainLabel", 3, false)]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("DomainLabel")]
    public string DomainLabel { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that, for Json.NET to call the parameterized constructor with correctly deserialized arguments, the constructor argument names must match the JSON property names.  But since `eventObject` and `Event` do not match, the `"Event"` property is not bound to the argument.  See e.b. [Json.net `JsonConstructor` constructor parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034838/3744182) or [JsonConstructor throws Exception even when the passed parameter is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034838/3744182).

Comment: You wrote, *I have no control on the class* so if you cannot fix the constructor argument name you will have to write a custom converter.  However, it seems you are also serializing with `TypeNameHandling.All`.  Do you need this also?  Is your JSON format flexible even if `EventLog<T>` cannot be changed?  Because if you do need TypeNameHandling you will have to manually parse the `$type` property in the converter (or do something tricky with a custom contract resolver).

Comment: From the type information, you are also serializing a `System.Object[]` rather than a `List<EventLog>`.  Do you need to do that?  Is that why you are using TypeNameHandling?