# Parameter values are not getting assigned in class constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

My Class

```
   [System.Serializable]
   public class StallData
   {
    public StallData(ulong stallID, stallSurfaceTextureData)
    {
      StallID = stallID;
      StallSurfaceTextureData = stallSurfaceTextureData;
    }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public ulong StallID{ get; private set; }

    [field: SerializeField]
    public StallSurfaceTextureData StallSurfaceTextureData { get; private set; }
}


[System.Serializable]
public class StallSurfaceTextureData
{
    public StallSurfaceTextureData( int floorTextureID, int leftTextureID, int right, int back)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat($" f {floorTextureID} l {leftTextureID} r {right} b {back}");

        BackWallTextureID = back;
        LeftWallTextureID = leftTextureID;
        RightWallTextureID = right;
        FloorTextureID = floorTextureID;
    }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int BackWallTextureID { get; private set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int LeftWallTextureID { get; private set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int RightWallTextureID { get;private  set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int FloorTextureID { get; private set; }
}
```

using newtonsoft-json when I am converting my JSON to this class I am getting back, left & right value 0 and for floor, I am getting the correct value.

I am unable to find the reason for it.

Unity version 2021.3.12f1

this is my JSON

```
{
  "StallID": 889448,
  "StallSurfaceTextureData": 
  {
    "BackWallWallTextureID": 0,
    "LeftWallWallTextureID": 1,
    "RightWallWallTextureID": 2,
    "FloorTextureID": 3
  }
}
```

I renamed the parameter name, and one time it worked then again I am getting the same issue.

**Edit:**
I have changed the parameter name in JSon but still the issue persists. The only way it is working is if I am keeping the parameter name and the variable name inside the class is same. I am not getting how the Parameter name is affecting the value assignment in the class?
for ex:
If I keep my class like this it will work

```
    [System.Serializable]
     public class StallSurfaceTextureData
     {
    public StallSurfaceTextureData( int floorTextureID, int leftWallTextureID, int rightWallTextureID, int backWallTextureID)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat($" f {floorTextureID} l {leftWallTextureID} r {rightWallTextureID} b {backWallTextureID}".ToGreen());

        BackWallTextureID = backWallTextureID;
        LeftWallTextureID = leftWallTextureID;
        RightWallTextureID = rightWallTextureID;
        FloorTextureID = floorTextureID;
    }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int BackWallTextureID { get; private set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int LeftWallTextureID { get; private set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int RightWallTextureID { get;private  set; }
    
    [field: SerializeField]
    public int FloorTextureID { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Could it be Id and ID not being the same in the json and the class? While FloorTextureID is same on both.

Comment: That's simply a typo: you fields in JSON are `...Id` you fields in c# are `...ID` => they are not found and keep their default values

Comment: I tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) - no any problem, I guess because you constructor input parameters are ignored since they are not exist

Comment: In the json you posted, all your "wall"-related variables are named "xxxWallWallxxx" while your variables in C# are named just "xxxWallxxx". Could this be your issue?

Comment: 1) Your properties `BackWallTextureID` and etc. have **private setters** so Json.NET won't call the setters unless you mark your properties with `[JsonProperty]`.  See [Private setters in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066947).  (`[SerializeField]` has no effect on Json.NET unless you are using some custom contract resolver that checks for the attribute and interprets it as equivalent to `[JsonProperty]`.)

Comment: 2) The reason the 2nd version of your `StallSurfaceTextureData` works is that it has a fully compatible constructor.  When your class has a single constructor which is parameterized, Json.NET it will call the constructor, **matching the constructor arguments to JSON properties by case-invariant name**.  See [JSON.net: how to deserialize without using the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017716) and [Json.net `JsonConstructor` constructor parameter names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43032552).  Do those three questions answer yours sufficiently, or do you need

Answer (score 1):

Unity need to have the same to the letter variables name in JSON and class.
You have `BackWallTextureID` in JSON and `BackWallTextureId` in class.

Answer (score 0):

I tried JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) - no any problem, I guess because you constructor input parameters are ignored since they are not exist for Newtonsoft.Json. If you want to use  a constructor, input parameters should be the same as json ( case insensitive by default).